# Position text above background photo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website and I am working on making it responsive. 
On larger screens there is an image on the left side, and some text on the right side, which works fine, but with smaller screen I want the photo to be placed below the text.

To achieve the desired behavior, I decided to make the photos the background photo, and mess around with the padding in order to place the text like I wanted. In the beginning I had put the photo in a separate column, but I read in a question on here that it should be better to use background photos.
This is fine on screens above and around 600px, but below this the text breaks and fills more of the screen vertically, meaning it will overlap the photo (I'll include a screenshot of this).
[image: Problem photo]

```
.box-1 {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/250.jpg?text=Om+os');
  background-position: bottom;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

I want the photo to align below the text, but since I have two boxes, one as described with an image on the left and text on the right on larger screens, and one with the image on the right and text on the left, I find this rather difficult, since I want both of them to have the photo on top and text below on small screens.

Comment: CSS Grid shoul be a good ideia... you can place the grid areas where you want (Desktop or mobile) with media queries

Comment: @LuísP.A. I'm using bootstrap with containers, rows and columns, wouldn't that overlap?

Comment: why don't you use `order-**-**` ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 pull-right">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="thumbnail" alt="History Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                           <p>
                           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                           
                           </p>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use the grid layout for this. Inside a row, you can give ***50% width*** for each section, for the larger screens make the **image to pull-right**.so that the text will come on the **left side of the image** and for **smaller screens**, the image will be on top and the text will be at the bottom.

check the below snippet

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 pull-right">
            <img src="./images/image.png" class="thumbnail" alt=" Image">
      </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="historyHeader title">
                 YOUR TEXT COME HERE
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I was already using the grid layout, but I didn't know I could pull the images to a side, thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try this yourself? When I do this the first box is fine since the photo is on the left, but I can't make it pull right.

Comment: yes, I have tried and pull-right is nothing but `float:right`

Comment: But that doesn't work either when I am trying to get the photo on the right and text on the left

Comment: ok, then remove the `pull-right` class because by default the image block is in the left side only. so the text will be on another side. when you change this to smaller screens image is on top the text will go down.